# Given a quadratic polynomial $p(x)=(ax+b)^2$, why do conclude that the discriminant must be less or equal to $0$ if $p(x)\ge 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm not sure why if $p(x) \ge 0$, then it must be that the discriminant is less of equal to $0$?

In the case when $p(x)>0$, then sure the discriminant in the quadratic formula must be negative because the expression is always positive.

However, if $p(x)=0$ then it could be the discriminant is greater or equal to $0$.

Comment: Your last sentence gives the impression that your $p(x)$ denotes some value of the polynomial (i.e. for some real number $x$) and not the quadratic polynomial itself. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AnneBauval: No, I'm speaking in general for any real $x$.

Comment: Then I do not understand your last sentence ($0$ is not a quadratic polynomial and has no discriminant). To answer the question of your title: the discriminant of $\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$ (for $\alpha\ne0$) is $\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma.$ hence the discriminant of $(ax+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ is $(2ab)^2-4a^2b^2=0.$

Comment: "However, if $p(x)=0$ then it could be the discriminant is greater or equal to 0."  **No,** if the discriminant is $> 0$ then there are two distinct roots.  However, if $p(x) = 0$, then there is only one root, which is given by $(ax + b) = 0.$

Comment: "However, if p(x)=0, then there is only one root, which is given by (ax+b)=0." **No** if $p(x)=0$ (in the sense specified by Joey's first comment) then $p$ is the zero polynomial. Its "roots" are all the real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $p(x)$ is nonnegative, it has at most one intersection with $x$-axis. That is, $p(x)=0$ has at most one root. This is equivalent to the discriminant being nonnegative.

I am not that sure about what your last sentence means. Can you elaborate on it?

Answer (score 0):

Your title is confusing: $p(X)=(aX+b)^2$ is a much stronger condition than $\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad p(x)\ge0.$

Let $p(X)=\alpha X^2+\beta X+\gamma,$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb R$ and $\alpha\ne0.$ Its discriminant is $\Delta=\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma.$

- $p(X)=(aX+b)^2$ (for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$) iff $\alpha=a^2,\beta=2ab,\gamma=b^2,$ i.e. iff $\alpha>0$ and $\gamma=\left(\frac\beta{2\sqrt\alpha}\right)^2,$ i.e. iff $\alpha>0$ and $\Delta=0.$
- $\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad p(x)\ge0$ iff $\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad \alpha\left(x+\frac\beta{2\alpha}\right)^2\ge\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}-\gamma,$ i.e. iff $\alpha>0$ and $\Delta\le0.$

Your last sentence remains mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what one means when they say  "$p(x)\ge 0$" or "$p(x) > 0$" or "p(x) =0".

"$p(x) \ge 0$" can have three meanings:

a) It can mean:  I have a specific $x$ in mind and for that specific $x$, $p(x) \ge 0$.  However for any other value of input we don't know anything about what ouput value the polynomial takes.

b) It can mean: For any possible $x\in \mathbb R$ it will always be the case that $p(x)\ge 0$ meaning for any possible $x_0$ it will either be $p(x_0) > 0$ or $p(x_0)=0$ (However we don't really know if there are any $x_0$ where $p(x_0) = 0$.  There *might* be, but we don't know.

c) It can mean: For any possible $x \in \mathbb R$ it will always be the case that $p(x)\ge 0$ and there is at one $x_1\in \mathbb R$ so that $p(x_1) = 0$.

Likewise "$p(x) > 0$" can mean two things.

a) For a specific $x$, $p(x) > 0$.

b) For every $x$, $p(x) > 0$.

And "$p(x) = 0$" can mean two things.

a) For a specific $x$, $p(x)=0$.

b) For every $x$, $p(x) = 0$.

Now.....  Here's the thing about discriminants.

If $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ then the equation $p(w) = 0$ for a specific $w$ will have two potential solutions.  $w= \frac {-b +\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}2$ or $w = \frac {-b + \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}2$.  Now, whether these solutions actually exist or not will depend on if $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ exist or whether the discriminant, $b^2 -4ac$ is positive or negative.

If $b^2 -4ac$ is positive than $\sqrt{b^2-4ac} > 0$ and there are two solutions.  That means there are two values of $x$ where $p(x)=0$ and there are other values of $x$ where $p(x) > 0$ and still other values of $x$ where $p(x) < 0$.

If $b^2 - 4ac=0$ then $\sqrt{b^2-4ac} =0$ and the two possible solutions are actually the same value,  $w = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a} =\frac {-b \pm 0}{2a} =-\frac b{2a}$.  This means there is exactly one value of $x$ where $p(x) =0$.  Now as there is only one it is not possible for the graph to *cross* the $x$ axis because if it crosses it must come back and cross again, and that means there'd but *two* values of $x$ where $p(x)=0$.  Thus we have for *every* value of $x$ either $p(x) \ge 0$ or for every value of $x$, $p(x) \le 0$. (Which one depends on if $a$ is positive or negative.)

But if $b^2 -4ac < 0$ then $\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}$ can not exist.  Therefore the two potential solutions can never happen.  So for absolutely *no* value does it ever occur that $p(x) =0$ and for all values of $x$ we always have $p(x) \ne 0$.  As $p(x)$ can never be $0$, $p(x)$ never *crosses* the $x$ axis so we either have for all possible values $x$ that $p(x) >0$ (if $a$ is positive) of $p(x) < 0$ (if $a$ is negative).

.... phew....

Now the answers to your questions are probably anticlimatic.

....

1a) For one value of $x$ (let's call it $w$ just so we don't confuse ourselves over whether $x$ means a specific or a general value) we have $p(w) \ge 0$.

We really don't know anything about the discriminant because we don't know anything about any *other* possible values of $x$.  We do know that it can't be the case where the discriminant is negative and $a$ is negative but any other possibility is possible.

1b) For every value of $x$ we will always have $p(x) \ge 0$.

Since $p(x)$ can't cross over the $x$-axis we can't have the discriminant positive.  So we either have the discriminant negative (in which case $p(x) > 0$ for all $x$) or we can have discriminant equal to zero (in which case the graph *touches* the $x$-axis *exactly* once at $x=-\frac b{2a}$) and the is exactly one $w=-\frac b{2a}$ where $p(w) = 0$.

So discriminant $\ge 0$.

1c)  For every $p(x)$ we have $p(x)\ge 0$ and there is at least one case where $p(x)=0$.

In this case we have exactly one $w = -\frac b{2a}$ where $p(w) = 0$ and in all other cases $p(x) > 0$.  In this case the discriminant is equal to $0$.

....

2a) There is a specifc value $w$ where $p(w)> 0$.

Just like 1a) we don't really know anything.

2b) For every possible $x$ we always have $p(x)>0$.

Then there are no $x$ where $p(x) =0$ so no solutions so the discriminant is negative.

3a)  There is a specific $w$ so that $p(w) =0$.

So there is one solution at least.  So $b^2 -4ac \ge 0$.  If it is equal to $0$ then $w=-\frac b2$ is the only solution.  But if $b^2 -4ac > 0$ then there is another $w_1$ where $p(w_1) = 0$.

3b) For every possible $x$ we always have $p(x) =0$.

This is impossible.

..... phew.....

Now on to your actual *title* which you never mention in the body.

If $p(x) = (ax+b)^2$ then $p(w) = 0$ has exactly one solution:

$p(w) = (aw+b)^2 = 0$ so
$aw+b = 0$ so
$w=-\frac ba$

and the discriminant must be equal to $0$.

And indeed:  If $p(x) = (ax+b)^2 = a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2$ then to put it in the form $p(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$ we have $A=a^2; B=2ab; c=b^2$ so the discriminant is $B^2 - 4AC = (2ab)^2 - 4(a^2)(b^2)= 4a^2b^2 - 4a^2b^2 =0$.

... Maybe your confusion comes from the variable $a,b$ *usually* mean the coeficients of the quatratic $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$.  In this case we are using them for something utterly different.